# Flutter Java android get data from file in /app_flutter folder

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, path

Hy everybody,

I need to know, how I cann get data from json file in this "/data/user/0/com.example.foo/app_flutter" path to "app_flutter" folder with java in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is note very clear, plus your path does not point to a file.
However have you tried dart:io to read a file, JSON.decode to parse  string into 
 a json,

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';


// ...

new File('/data/user/0/com.example.foo/app_flutter/config.json')
    .readAsString()
    .then((fileContents) => JSON.decode(fileContents))
    .then((jsonData) {
        // do whatever you want with the data
    });
```

Comment: Look into Java.io.File Class and Json encoding/decoding in Java.